# How could I show a child component into Modal box? Angular

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, components, parent-child

I have 2 components: parent & child.
I want that the child component appears in a modal box. How could I do this please?

Comment: just google angular modal, you will find some npm packages or google angular modal boostrap

Comment: thank you for your answer but what i found on google are examples of modals on the same component, for me the button is in the parent component and the content that I want to show in the modal is in the child component

Comment: haven't tried but you could use the <app-child> selector inside your modal html, basically 3 lines of code and child logic is in child component. You pass data between with event emitters and data binding, it should work. Or add libraries like Material, usually I avoid them if I need 1 thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you check out Angular Material's dialog component, you can pass a component to its MatDialog service. All you would need to do is inject MatDialog in the parent component constructor and attach the opening of a dialog with your child component to whatever event you want (a button click, from what I've understood)!

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ParentComponent,
    ChildComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    MatDialogModule
  ]
})
export class ExampleModule { }

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `
    <button (click)="openDialog()"></button>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(ChildComponent);
  }
}
```

Comment: @erij-maherzia-ben-brahim no problem at all!

Comment: please I found a problem , when I used dialog I have to put into it the ChildComponent in a static way but me I want it to recieve the data from the parent @lincoln-alves

Comment: Material's dialog service has support for data sharing  (https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component ) .

You just need to add an `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA` injection token to the child component and pass the data you need as a parameter of MatDialog.open!